# How to draw an algebraic set with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to draw any algebraic curve with TikZ. For instance, I would like to draw the set of points M whose coordinates `$(x, y)$` satisfy the relation:

- `$y^2 - x^3 + x = 0$`
- or `$x^2 + 5y^2 = 1$`
- etc.

Is there a procedure to do so?

Thanks

Comment: Have you try to search "implicit curves" instead of the more specific "algebraic curve" from the so cut algebraic geometry ?